# Stylistic? approach to copy constructor signature in Java

Tags: java

I have an abstract class `Stack` and a class that extends it: `MyStack`. I need to make a copy constructor for `MyStack`. Is it better to pass in only `MyStack` objects, or any `Stack` object?

```
public MyStack(Stack other)
public MyStack(MyStack other)
```

Both will work, I think, because I can use the methods defined in `Stack` to look at and copy all the data either way; the "stack-ness" will be copied regardless of which approach I use.

I can't find any 'best approach' for this. Does one exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are similar in terms of implementation complexity, then you should go for the most general one, i.e. `public MyStack(Stack other)` as it gives more flexibility. And if somebody wants to pass a `MyStack` it is also possible.

If accepting a `Stack` makes the code more complex then you should make a balanced decision...

As an example, `ArrayList` accepts a `Collection` in [its copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29).